# Mounting DVD when unable to open DVD player

Tags: mount, dvd

I am very new to Linux so learning as I go. I have a new PC that has a internal DVD player installed. I would like to use it but there is no button to open the DVD like you see on most laptops/PCs. I have tried the eject command in terminal and I receive the following:

eject: /dev/cdrom: not found mountpoint or device with the given name

I understand that I need to mount the dvd player first and when I run the command sudo lsblk there is no dvd device listed so that I can select a device to mount.

```
AME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0    62M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1611
loop1     7:1    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
loop2     7:2    0  63.2M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1623
loop3     7:3    0  55.1M  1 loop  /snap/cups/774
loop4     7:4    0  55.1M  1 loop  /snap/cups/803
loop5     7:5    0 237.3M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1883
loop6     7:6    0 178.4M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/1860
loop7     7:7    0 400.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop8     7:8    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop9     7:9    0  81.3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop10    7:10   0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop11    7:11   0  37.1M  1 loop  /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
loop12    7:12   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/582
loop13    7:13   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/592
loop14    7:14   0    48M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/16778
loop15    7:15   0    48M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17029
loop16    7:16   0   284K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop17    7:17   0   284K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda2    8:2    0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                   /
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1G  0 part  
└─sdb2    8:18   0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

I have ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed. I am obviously missing something but my limited knowledge is showing here. Thankyou for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the make and model of the computer? Never heard of one that had no way to open. Are you sure it does not have a disk in it?

Comment: It is and has been for many years `sr0`, not `cdrom`, but you don't have that either. You're probably confusing something else for a optical drive and it's unlikely a new PC comes with one anyway. So, again, brand/model?

Comment: The brand on the case is Thermaltake. However it was a custom upgraded desktop from a basic model without a DVD. It has a Dual Layer DVD+RW Optical Drive installed. It doesn't have a disk in it has never been opened since I bought it.

Comment: So on inspection inside the desktop it appears as though the supplier has neglected to install the dvd (despite being paid for).

Comment: So you were confusing a bay cover with an actual drive. Optical drives have a button, the only exception is some of the very rare slot-in type.

Comment: As I said, I am a novice to this and I appreciate everyone's assistance. However if something was paid for and expected to be installed then you can understand my confusion when it looks different to what I am used to with a Windows PC. We all have different experience levels and have to learn somewhere.

Comment: @Lee, some systems just have a blank cover that completely hides the disc drive. Your question was fine IMO. I've been driving several decades and recently had to ask where the gear selector was in a hire car.